# Median Calculation of List of Integers without using heap

Tags: python, python-3.x, median

### References

Using those references:

- [rolling median implementations benchmark](https://gist.github.com/f0k/2f8402e4dfb6974bfcf1)
- [FAST RUNNING MEDIAN USING AN INDEXABLE SKIPLIST](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577073/)
- [Calculate the median of a billion numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2571358/7690982)
- [Find running median from a stream of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10696252/7690982)

### Code

A code was written to calculate the Median with the [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) library:

```
from itertools import islice
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
import random
import time

start_time = time.time()


class Median(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = islice(iterable, None)
        self._sortedlist = SortedList(self._iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        self_sortedlist = self._sortedlist
        # print(self_sortedlist)
        length = len(self_sortedlist)
        half = length // 2
        if length % 2 == 0:
            yield (self_sortedlist[half] + self_sortedlist[half - 1]) // 2
        elif length % 2 == 1:
            yield self_sortedlist[half]


def main():
    m, n = 1000, 1500000
    data = [random.randrange(m) for i in range(n)]
    # print("Random Data: ", data)
    result = list(Median(data))
    print("Result: ", result)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

### Explanation

#### Random Number Generator

The following code generates data within the Range `m` and quantity `n`.

```
m, n = 1000, 15000000
data = [random.randrange(m) for i in range(n)]
```

#### Median

The Median class sorts the list of numbers and if `n` is odd, returns the middle item with `yield self_sortedlist[half]`. Or if `n` is even, returns the mean of two middle itens of the list with `yield (self_sortedlist[half] + self_sortedlist[half - 1]) // 2`

### Question

How do I improve the code performance? Because for a large list (100 milion), it takes `--- 186.7168517112732 seconds---` on my computer.

Comment: sorting has time complexity `O(n log n)`. You may want to look into [Medians of Medians](https://brilliant.org/wiki/median-finding-algorithm/) (scroll down for a python implementation) which has linear time complexity.

Comment: Why do you use integer division for a list with even length? Shouldn't it be a regular division of the two center values in the sorted list?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding; the use of heaps and such clever data structures is needed to maintain a *rolling median*, i.e. you have to return the current median after every number in the input. If you want to call it only once on the final list, then a simple quickselect is enough - that gets you to O(n) time. (If you were to use this algorithm for the rolling mean case, you would need O(1+2+..+n) = O(n^2) time, which is why heaps and other structures are used.)

Comment: @Ant Thanks, i think I misunderstood It. Will study more about heaps. I think that TimSort is already the best algorithm for my case. Just need to use the correct sorting for the data structure that is being used (still learning, so i can be incorrect).

Comment: Timsort is a sorting algorithm, and it takes O(n log n) time. Quickselect is *not* a sorting algorithm, and it takes O(n) time. Quickselect is much faster than timsort for this use case; the key observation is that to get the median you don't need to sort the whole vector, just as if you want to compute the minimum you don't need to sort the whole vector, you can just do one pass over the elements. With the median (and in general with order statistics) it's more complicated, so you use quickselect, but it still has a O(n) performance, much better than your sorting approach which is O(n log n)

Comment: @danieltakeshi What do you mean by regular division? The `//` operator conducts integer division, i.e. `5.5 // 2 = 2`. That's not how the median is defined.

Comment: @DanielLenz Oh, It was to reuse the number as Integer. Just as the data type of the input. However, if the precision of the program is needed for decimal numbers, then it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Performance

I instrumented your code differently:

```
def main():
    m, n = 1000, 15000000
    start_time = time.time()
    data = [random.randrange(m) for i in range(n)]
    print("--- %s seconds to generate" % (time.time() - start_time))
    # print("Random Data: ", data)
    start_time = time.time()
    result = SortedList(data)
    print("--- %s seconds to sort" % (time.time() - start_time))
    start_time = time.time()
    result = list(Median(data))
    print("Result: ", result)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

For me, the results were:

```
--- 7.407598257064819 seconds to generate
--- 4.535749673843384 seconds to sort
Result:  [500]
--- 5.01109504699707 seconds ---
```

This shows that the generation of the random input takes longer than finding the median, and that 90% of `Median()` is spent sorting (probably most of the rest is caused by converting between lists and iterators).  You're unlikely to get large gains through modifications to your own part of the code.

I got better results by using Python's built-in `sorted()`.  We don't need any of the extra functionality of `SortedList` (maintaining the invariant through adds and deletes), and a single sort (mostly in native code) gives these results:

```
def median(values):
    sortedlist = sorted(values)
    length = len(sortedlist)
    half = length // 2
    # return not yield; see "General review"
    if length % 2 == 0:
        return (sortedlist[half] + sortedlist[half - 1]) // 2
    else:
        return sortedlist[half]

def main():
    m, n = 1000, 15000000
    start_time = time.time()
    data = [random.randrange(m) for i in range(n)]
    print("--- %s seconds to generate" % (time.time() - start_time))
    # print("Random Data: ", data)
    start_time = time.time()
    result = sorted(data)
    print("--- %s seconds to sort" % (time.time() - start_time))
    start_time = time.time()
    result = median(data)
    print("Result: ", result)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

```
--- 7.638948202133179 seconds to generate
--- 3.118924617767334 seconds to sort
Result:  500
--- 3.3397886753082275 seconds ---
```

---

### General review

I don't see why you `yield` a single value, rather than simply returning.  Is there a need for `Median()` to be iterable?

Given that `length` is an integer, if `length % 2` is not 0, it must be 1 - so the `elif` could easily be `else`.

Comment: You are right on the General Review, yield is only necessary for the running median, so i changed to `return` and the result to `result = Median(data)`. Else was used instead of elif. Is there any algorithm that generates the list on an improved way, faster?

Comment: Yes, use Python's built-in sort for a one-time sorting of a list - see edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to time something, you should time just that. When I ran your original code, I got  6.023478031158447 seconds. When I instead did

```
start_time = time.time()
result = list(Median(data))
end_time = time.time()
print("Result: ", result, end_time-start_time)
```

I got  1.8368241786956787. Note that calling `time.time()` before the `print` statement means that the execution of the `print` statement isn't included in your calculation of elapsed time.

I also tried

```
import statistics
start_time = time.time()
result = statistics.median(data)
end_time = time.time()
print("Result: ", result, end_time-start_time)
```

and got 0.7475762367248535.

What do mean by "not using heap", and why do you want that? What makes you think SortedList doesn't use a heap? If you're going to use pre-made functions, why not just use the pre-made `median` function?

Comment: Just taking some challenges to learn Python. It was without heap, because there are many answers and duplicates. Thanks for the tip for measuring the time.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Toby now the program takes:

`--- 7.169409990310669 seconds to finish the program---` instead of `--- 186.7168517112732 seconds---` for 100 milion numbers.

One other improvement I made was to add an extra optimization on the random generating algorithm, using numpy. So `numpy.sort()` was used to sort the numpy array at the start of `median()`, because it is faster for numpy arrays.

#### Code

```
import time
import numpy

start_time0 = time.time()


def median(values):
    sortedlist =  numpy.sort(values)
    length = len(sortedlist)
    half = length // 2

    if length % 2 == 0:
        return (sortedlist[half] + sortedlist[half - 1]) // 2
    else:
        return sortedlist[half]


def main():

    m, n = 1000, 100000000
    # Random Number Generator
    start_time = time.time()
    data = numpy.random.randint(1, m, n)
    print("--- %s seconds to numpy random---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    # Median
    start_time = time.time()
    result = median(data)
    print("Result: ", result)
    print("--- %s seconds to find the Median---" % (time.time() - start_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
    print("--- %s seconds to finish the program---" % (time.time() - start_time0))
```

Comment: In this case, you might want to consider posting another question if you want another review? As it is, your newly refactored code isn't more helpful than the already accepted answer :)

Comment: Oh forgive us - it was difficult to see the implicit change. Hopefully [my edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/201741/2) makes it easier for others to see

Answer (score 0):

just a note :
you can enhance just a tidbit by defining the name in the list comprehension

from

```
data = [random.randrange(m) for i in range(n)]
```

to

```
data = [random.randrange(m) for num in range(n)]
```